# What is the equivalent of anchor in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

i need to resize an element when the main window is resized, i thought at anchor which is what i used in Visual Basic .NET, but i dosen't found it in Qt Designer, What i should use ?

Details :
The element to resize : label
The main form is named : Form

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Qt, you use layouts for this. The base class is QLayout. In the Designer, you first assign a layout to your main window, and then insert the label into the layout. There are several types of layouts, and they have several properties that define the size behavior of its managed widgets.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer but can you be more precise ? have you got an exemple ?

Comment: Layouts in qt are not similar to anchors in winforms. In winform you can put an element anywhere and anchor it to an edge. You can't do that with qt. Especially if you have a bunch of elements.